# How to set a sticky header in a list view in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a list view that holds some values, let's say 1 to 10. I'm showing those values in the list tile. After 10 list tiles, I have a heading called "Next" and after that heading, I have another 10 values ranging from 11 to 20. Now what I want is that when "Next" reaches the top of the page, it sticks on there and the next values that are 11 to 20 keep scrolling. like the sticky_headers package but I don't want to use it. Is there any way this is achievable maybe without using any third-party packages?

The following code achieves what I want but I want to do this without any third party packages:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sticky_headers/sticky_headers.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.arrow_back_ios,
              size: 16,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          ),
          title: const Text('Results'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    ListTile(
                      leading: Text('1'),
                    ),
                    ListTile(
                      leading: Text('2'),
                    ),
                    ListTile(
                      leading: Text('3'),
                    ),
                    ListTile(
                      leading: Text('4'),
                    ),
                    StickyHeader(
                      header: Container(
                        width: double.infinity,
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        child: Text(
                          'Heading',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                      ),
                      content: Column(
                          children: List.generate(20, (index) {
                        return ListTile(
                          leading: Text((index + 5).toString()),
                        );
                      })),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes it's possible to achieve that but without the context of your code  it would be hard to understand your thought process. Please consider adding some snippet of code.

Comment: @Davis added some code

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using `CustomScrollView`, `SliverAppBar`,SliverList

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: [
            SliverAppBar(
              leading: IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(
                  Icons.arrow_back_ios,
                  size: 16,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              ),
              title: const Text('Results'),
              pinned: true,
            ),
            SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
                ListTile(
                  leading: Text('1'),
                ),
                ListTile(
                  leading: Text('2'),
                ),
                ListTile(
                  leading: Text('3'),
                ),
                ListTile(
                  leading: Text('4'),
                ),
              ]),
            ),
            SliverPersistentHeader(
              pinned: true,
              delegate: _StickyHeaderDelegate(
                child: Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  child: const Text(
                    'Heading',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    leading: Text((index + 5).toString()),
                  );
                },
                childCount: 20,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _StickyHeaderDelegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  final Widget child;

  _StickyHeaderDelegate({required this.child});

  @override
  double get minExtent => 0;

  @override
  double get maxExtent => 100; // Adjust this value according to your needs

  @override
  Widget build(
      BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    return child;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(covariant _StickyHeaderDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return child != oldDelegate.child;
  }
}
```

Comment: The header doesn't stay there for all the below list items if I keep scrolling.

Comment: @dipansh had the same problem – change the minExtent value to suit your needs. You might also wrap the contents in build() into a container with background color. eg. `Widget build(BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) { return SafeArea(child: Container(color: Theme.of(context).appBarTheme.backgroundColor, constraints: BoxConstraints.tightFor(height: 104), child: child));}`